# java mongodb repairdatabase ()

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there a way to call MongoDB's db.repairDatabase() function from the java driver?

I tried the following :

```
db.command("repairDatabase",1);
```

but I had an errmsg with "bad option"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following and it worked without error:

```
@Test
public void shouldNotErrorWhenCallingRepairDatabase() throws UnknownHostException {
    // given
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    DB database = mongoClient.getDB("database");

    // when
    CommandResult result = database.command(new BasicDBObject("repairDatabase", 1));

    // then
    assertThat(result, is(notNullValue()));
    assertThat(result.ok(), is(true));
}
```

Can you post more information on the error please?